# Javafx TextArea. change text without evoking textchange

Tags: javafx, textarea

Can I change the text of a TextArea (e.g. by using setText()) without evoking the textProperty listeners?

An example: Everytime the text changes I perform a linebreak (with a user set line length). This linebreak (with setText()) should not evoke a new TextChange event.

Comment: Why can't you just consume the event as soon as it occurs?

Comment: i can check whether the oldString without newlines equals the newString without newlines, but i dont find this a nice solution..

Comment: Just check `newValue.endsWith("\n")`. But, I am sure there is more to it, why would you want not to invoke `textProperty()` listener? If you show us the whole scenario may be we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Short answer: no. If you change the text, any change listeners registered get notified. Perhaps explain more completely what you are trying to do?